# x86 assembly GAS, padding

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

Is it possible to pad a certain amount of times depending on the current location counter?

In NASM you can do something like this

```
times value - ($ $$) db 0
```

Is there a coresponding way of doing this using the gas syntax?
(The ammount of bytes i wish to pad is unknown, only the max number is known)

Comment: `.fill` is the equivalent directive.

Comment: It's unclear what you want, but `gas` has `.align` if you want to pad to a specific alignment and it also has `.fill`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to align use `.align` directive, And if you want to allocate stuff by hand you need to use `.space` directive. The second one should be used in the `.bss` section.